# Root HTC One m7 with Ubuntu

Tags: android, root, htc

Is there a easy way to root HTC One M7(Lolipop) with Ubuntu 14.04 LTS? I am a beginner with Ubuntu.

Comment: I don't think this is possible yet.

Comment: You might want to check the android forums. The vast majority of rooting methods I've seen require Windows. I've been able to accomplish this type of thing with a different android device via Windows under virtualbox.

Comment: I like that suggestion. @amon, They generally have an Ubuntu section of the guide on the forums.

Comment: Yes it is possible. Much easier that in Windows. you do not need any drivers for that.